# more user friendly password reset process

Tags: password, reset

Am writing a software to help my uncle with invoice creation. It has a login interface and each of his employees is supposed to have a cashier id. I was thinking how the best mechanism the cashier password reset should be reset. Should i make them answer a question or let a sole admin be responsible for that?

Comment: Depends, when do they use the system: is a manager always physically present when a cashier logs in, or can a cashier log in remotely for some other purpose (updating time sheets or something)?

Comment: For small systems, let the admin do it. Easier to audit.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, @pjc50. If the cashier can only access the system when a manger is around, just lump that into the "manager override" pattern, which is very well-known to cashiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few methods that have been used in the past by other systems that I have worked on.

- User has to input their date of hire along with a unique password on first entry and for all future password resets.
- All employees have a default patterned password that leverages bits of information from date of hire, employee id, and initials. This will expire based on standard company security settings.

Now if you have access to a cam at the log in points then you could possibly leverage some of the different facial recognition software that is out there and have first log in success be based person logging in matching employee id photo on record.  This method would be the most secure and no passwords would have to be remembered.

Comment: Yeah, thats more effective if those details would have been taken. But this is a small business that needed some automation. I'll incoporate what you said. Perhaps make it a secret question answering process